# High memory usage issue with metal using custom CIFilter

Tags: swift, memory, scenekit, metal, cifilter

I’m working on a game in SceneKit, where I’ve made a custom CIKernel filter to create scaled passes of what’s on the screen in Metal (which is needed for many other reasons for this project).

It works well, and the CPU and FPS are low and steady. The issue I’m facing is that the memory usage is very high, about 1GB. Before using Metal, I used pure CiFilters for the same effect, and the memory was about 200mb, but CPU and FPS were terrible, so that is the reason I re-wrote the function in Metal.

The code below is what is used to make scaled passes out of a CIImage being sent.

Does anyone see an issue or something I’ve missed to fix the high memory usage? Maybe adding CVPixelBufferPool or changing the pixel formats? I’m clueless.

Thanks!

```
class ImageEffect: CIFilter {

    private let kernel: CIKernel

    var inputImage: CIImage?
    
    // Effect parameters
    var textureCache: CVMetalTextureCache?
    let device: MTLDevice?
    let ciContext: CIContext?
    let commandQueue: MTLCommandQueue?
    var commandBuffer: MTLCommandBuffer?
    var pixelBuffer: CVPixelBuffer?
    let attrs = [kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey: Int(kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA),
                 kCVPixelBufferCGImageCompatibilityKey: kCFBooleanTrue,
         kCVPixelBufferCGBitmapContextCompatibilityKey: kCFBooleanTrue,
                   kCVPixelBufferMetalCompatibilityKey: kCFBooleanTrue] as CFDictionary;
    let scales = Array<Float>([1.0, 1.0, 1.0])
    var passTex = [MTLTexture]();
    var passImg = [CIImage]();

    override init() {
        let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "default", withExtension: "metallib")!
        let data = try! Data(contentsOf: url)
        
        // Set up support objects
        device = MTLCreateSystemDefaultDevice();
        ciContext = CIContext();
        commandQueue = device?.makeCommandQueue();
        CVMetalTextureCacheCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, nil, device!, nil, &textureCache);
        
        kernel = try! CIKernel(functionName: "imageeffect", fromMetalLibraryData: data) // (2)
        super.init()
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    override var outputImage: CIImage? {
        guard let inputImage = self.inputImage else { return nil }
        let inputExtent = inputImage.extent
        pixelBuffer = nil;
        passTex = [];
        passImg = [];
        
        let w = inputExtent.width;
        let h = inputExtent.height;
     
        CVPixelBufferCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, Int(w), Int(h), kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA, attrs, &pixelBuffer);
        ciContext!.render(inputImage, to: pixelBuffer!);
  
        CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(pixelBuffer!, CVPixelBufferLockFlags(rawValue: 0))
        let inputTex = PixelBufferToMTLTexture(pixelBuffer: pixelBuffer!);
  
        // Add first pass
        passTex.append(inputTex)
        passImg.append(CIImage(mtlTexture: inputTex)!)
        commandBuffer = commandQueue?.makeCommandBuffer();

        // Effect textures settings
        let mpsScale = MPSImageLanczosScale(device: device!);
        let desc = MTLTextureDescriptor()
        desc.depth = 1
        desc.allowGPUOptimizedContents = true;
        desc.pixelFormat = MTLPixelFormat.rgba16Float;
        desc.usage = [.renderTarget, .shaderRead, .shaderWrite]
        desc.width = Int(w/2)
        desc.height = Int(h/2)
     
        // Queue up scale and blur kernels for the rest of the passes
        var k = 0
        for scale in scales{
            var tex = device!.makeTexture(descriptor: desc)
            let prevTex = passTex[k]
     
            mpsScale.encode(commandBuffer: commandBuffer!, sourceTexture: prevTex, destinationTexture: tex!);
            
            passTex.append(tex!)
            passImg.append(CIImage(mtlTexture: tex!)!)

            desc.width = desc.width / 2
            desc.height = desc.height / 2
            k = k + 1
        }
     
        // Execute scale kernels and wait for them to finish
        commandBuffer!.commit();
        commandBuffer!.waitUntilCompleted();
                 
        let roiCallback: CIKernelROICallback = { _, rect -> CGRect in  // (4)
            return rect
        }
        
        let outImg = self.kernel.apply(extent: inputExtent,
                                   roiCallback: roiCallback,
                                   arguments: [passImg[0], passImg[1], passImg[2], 0, 0])
        
        CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(pixelBuffer!, CVPixelBufferLockFlags(rawValue: 0))
          
        return outImg?.oriented(.downMirrored);
    }
    

    func PixelBufferToMTLTexture(pixelBuffer:CVPixelBuffer) -> MTLTexture
    {
        var texture:MTLTexture!
        let width = CVPixelBufferGetWidth(pixelBuffer)
        let height = CVPixelBufferGetHeight(pixelBuffer)
        let format : MTLPixelFormat = .rgba8Unorm
        var textureRef : CVMetalTexture?;
        let status = CVMetalTextureCacheCreateTextureFromImage(nil, textureCache!, pixelBuffer, nil, format, width, height, 0, &textureRef)

        if(status == kCVReturnSuccess)
        {
            texture = CVMetalTextureGetTexture(textureRef!)
        }

        return texture;
    }

}
```

Comment: Why is pixelBuffer a property? You're creating a new one every time outputImage is called, but you don't get rid of it when you're done. I don't think it's leaking, but it's wasting memory to hold onto it when you aren't going to reuse it. You probably want to just allocate one and reuse it; you shouldn't need a pool for that.

Comment: Same thing with `passImg` and I think several of your other variables. You're holding onto them after you're done (so holding all the memory), but you don't actually reuse them; you just clear them immediately before reuse

Comment: Thank you so for the help and input. We'll test this.

Comment: Though there can be better approaches to achieve this the problem I see here which might be causing memory spike is your command buffer, because you are adding all the scale operations for all textures in  in one command buffer and you commit them all together, the entire memory is released only after command buffer is complete. That means it will keep  on holding strong references to older textures even when their processing is done. I would advice you create new command buffer for each input texture in your loop and commit it at the end of iteration. That way memory will be released quickly.

Comment: And since all the command buffers are coming from same command queue they would be in sync, i.e. FIFO automatically.

Answer (score 2):

It's really not advisable to do your own custom Metal processing inside of a `CIFilter`s `outputImage` method.

Some background:
A `CIImage` is basically just a *receipt* for creating an image, i.e., it stores all the instructions that should be performed during rendering. When you apply a `CIFilter` to a `CIImage` (i.e., setting it as `inputImage` of the filter and then getting the `outputImage`), you will get a new image that contains the instructions of the input image plus the instructions added by this filter. "Instruction" in most cases usually refers to applying a `CIKernel` with the image as one of the parameters.

The real processing happens later when you tell a `CIContext` to create an actual image from a `CIImage`. Core Image will then look at the instruction graph stored in the image, optimize it, allocate potentially needed intermediate resources, and queue the actual work on the GPU.

The last part is important here: Ideally you let Core Image do all the resource allocation because it knows best what to cache and what to (re-)use when. In your filter you are doing that manually and actually at the wrong time. You are creating an additional `CIContext` (which is not the one that will render the `outputImage`) and manually create buffers and Metal resources, thereby disrupting the natural Core Image "flow".

I would recommend the following:

- You don't need to use `MPSImageLanczosScale`. There is the `CILanczosScaleTransform` that does exactly the same.
- Don't employ your own Metal pipeline. Instead, apply other `CIFilter`s before you pass their results to your kernel.
- Don't create any buffers, contexts, or Metal objects on your filter. Let Core Image handle that for you.

Maybe like so:

```
override var outputImage: CIImage? {
    guard let inputImage = self.inputImage else { return nil }
    let inputExtent = inputImage.extent
    
    let scaleFilter = CIFilter.lanczosScaleTransform()
    scaleFilter.inputImage = inputImage
    scaleFilter.scale = 0.5

    var passImg: [CIImage]()
    for scale in scales {
        passImg.append(scaleFilter.outputImage!)
        scaleFilter.scale /= 2.0
    }

    let roiCallback: CIKernelROICallback = { _, rect -> CGRect in
        return rect
    }
    
    let outImg = self.kernel.apply(extent: inputExtent,
                               roiCallback: roiCallback,
                               arguments: [passImg[0], passImg[1], passImg[2], 0, 0])
      
    return outImg?.oriented(.downMirrored);
}
```

(You need to `import CoreImage.CIFilterBuiltins` to get `CIFilter.lanczosScaleTransform()`.)

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! This makes a lot sense. We'll see how we can optimize the code based your answer.